# Issues when deploying asp.net mvc app to iis

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

(Program's function is to upload Excel files, store them in the database, download them, search for individual records, and creating invoices of certain records by uploading an Excel sheet with some keys in them and filling the info in for each record provided.)

So now it's time to deploy. I thought it was as simple as publishing with VS and putting it on the server. Boy was I wrong! I've been stuck for a week and still can't get it working completely on the IIS instance on my desktop or laptop, and I tried twice on the production server but that failed as well.

My question is, what steps do I have to take in order to get an MVC app I develop working on any computer that doesn't necessarily have visual studio ?

Steps I took towards getting it published:

App Pool: Managed pipeline mode: Integrated; .Net Framework v4.0.30319; Process Model Identity: LocalSystem/Network Service (both work, if I give them permission in SQL Management studio)

Connection Strings: When developing, *Datasource=(LocalDB)\v11.0*  and AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\myDB.mdf

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\PRICELISTDB.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="ServiceableItemContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0; AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\PRICELISTDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="SalesItemContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PRICELISTDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I've tried using Data Source=SQLEXPRESS and initialcatalog=Pricing as well.

I keep getting errors, either the database cannot be found or "CREATE TABLE permission denied in database". I finally got it working on my laptop with no permission/security issues but it doesn't upload my excel files, it just returns the view back without taking any action so I think IIS needs to be set to accept files. (the same code in visual studio works perfectly)

Comment: Firstly, have you made sure that the folders that the website is stored in have full access for IISUSR? (or IIS_USR i forget which). Secondly, check the user access on the database for the user that you are setting in the connectionString. I don't use MS_SQL myself so I can't be more helpful there.

Comment: You need to try an deal with each problem individually then post the specific problem when you get stuck, there is no single set of steps we can give you to ensure you have no problems, there are too many variables involved. As a start though if you have `Integrated Security` enabled, then your IIS app pool user needs the relevant permissions in the database, alternatively use a sql server user and you can put username and pass in the connection string.

Comment: oki, ill do what @DanielCasserly said (give permission to iis) and then find the individual problems. Already gave app pool dbowner schema in the database.

Answer (score 0):

`(LocalDb)\v11.0` *is* SQL Express, and it's only available within the confines of Visual Studio. On your production server, you should be using a real SQL Server instance. Set up SQL Server, preferably on a different server than the one your website is running on, and then change your connection string to that.

You can actually use the `Web.Release.config` transform to change your connection string in `Web.config` to this automatically when you publish with the Release  config in Visual Studio.

Comment: omg its chris pratt !! -- I've tried with a real instance of sqlserver as well (not localdb). In the end I got the CREATE TABLE permission denied" (even with permission given to app pool, user created in ssms, file permissions granted . I'm using Entity framework so it tries to make it's own table in the DB. I think I'm gonna try get the create table scripts from my localdb and put that in a new server. of course my fingers will be crossed while doing this.